# Django __unicode__ extended Auth_User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

I'm extending a the `auth.models.User` but I'm having troubles to implement the `__unicode__` methode.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Artist(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Now how to I access the `user` fields as I want to return the name for Django Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    # fields

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{first_name} {last_name}".format(
            **dict(
                first_name=self.user.first_name,
                last_name=self.user.last_name
            )
        )
```

Though `User` already has a function to concat the name fields, so this will work too:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "{0}".format(self.user.get_full_name())
```

Or even

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.get_full_name()
```